# compiling Lua source with host C++ application

Tags: c++, lua, embedding

I'll be quick:

I have a C++ application that embeds Lua. Until now I have just used a pre-compiled lib that I link to the app. I would like to make a new approach by including the Lua source code and compile from scratch. What all would I need to do?

I'm running gcc v 4.4.3 in ubuntu 11.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Include the lua source code as included in the library - leave out the .c files which contain a main()
2. Make the proper #define for your operating system (see the Lua makefile for which ones to use)
3. Compile.

Comment: Indeed it is as easy as that. Tried that some weeks ago and works like a charm. Also let myself get inspired from the make files.

Comment: Remove `print.c` as well. See INSTALL for a list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [Binding Code to Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua).